# iPython notebook not loading

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So my iPython notebook comes up in my browser (chrome) and when I open my specific notebook a new tab opens. However the work does not load up! The page also freezes. Is this an iPython issue or something wrong with the file? Was working yesterday. I've restared comp etc. but no luck

Update: just tried renaming notebook to open again with no luck

Update 2: One has now shown up - but can't do anything with it! Is iPython simply extremely extremely slow...

Comment: Can you provide a link to the notebook contents? I'm assuming it's some form of HTML/JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it possible that one of the cells got a lot of output data?
if so,
try editing the file manually (with notepad++ or something like this), and delete cell's output

Comment: Yes it does seem like there was some large output which has now been removed. Although still be very very slow. I converted it into a .py file and was able to edit it that way. Shame there's no RStudio for Python